# Why using a variable as index of a list-item does not retrieve that item with \clist_item:Nn?

Tags: expl3, latex3, comma-separated-list

For some reason, using a variable as index of a list-item does not work for retrieving that item. But using a number instead of a variable works. Why?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\begin{document}

  \clist_new:N\myList
  \clist_set:Nn\myList{1,south}

  \int_new:N\myCounter
  \int_set:Nn\myCounter{1}
  \int_do_until:nNnn{\myCounter}={\clist_count:N\myList+1}
    { \regex_set:Nn\myExp{[0-9]+}
      % following line doesn't work
      %\regex_match:NnT\myExp{\clist_item:Nn\myList{\int_use:N\myCounter}}
      % but as soon as we change \int_use:N\myCounter to 1, it works
      \regex_match:NnT\myExp{\clist_item:Nn\myList{1}}
        { (is a number) % output
        }
      \int_incr:N\myCounter
    }

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a regex against the *literal* text `\clist_item:Nn\myList{\int_use:N\myCounter}`, not the result of executing it. In the case where you use an explicit `1`, that works, but not when you have no `1` present.

Fixing that by expansion, and also using standard variable names plus a step loop (seems easier here), I'd have

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{expl3}

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
  \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { 1 , south }
  \regex_set:Nn \l_tmpa_regex { [0-9]+ }
  \int_step_inline:nn { \clist_count:N \l_tmpa_clist }
    {
      \exp_args:NNf \regex_match:NnT \l_tmpa_regex
        { \clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {#1} }
        { (is ~ a ~ number ) }
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Comment: BTW, there's no benefit in pre-compiling the regex if you do it in every step of the loop ...

Comment: Isn't `\clist_map_inline:Nn` easier?

Comment: @egreg My guess was that the OP wants the position number too ...

Answer (score 5):

The argument type `n` in `\regex_match:NnT` states that the argument is passed “literally”, with no processing, but you need the item, not the instructions needed to retrieve it. You could define a variant

```
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \regex_match:nn { ne } { T,F,TF }
```

and use `\regex_match:NeT`, but it's actually much easier with `\clist_map_inline:Nn` that will access the clist's items one at a time:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\clist_new:N \l_bp_mylist_clist
\clist_set:Nn \l_bp_mylist_clist {1,south}

\clist_map_inline:Nn \l_bp_mylist_clist
 {
  \regex_match:nnTF { [0-9]+ } { #1 }
   { #1~is~a~number \par }
   { #1~is~not~a~number \par }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need to use the item number,

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\clist_new:N \l_bp_mylist_clist
\clist_set:Nn \l_bp_mylist_clist {1,south}

\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \regex_match:nn { ne } { T,F,TF }

\int_step_inline:nn { \clist_count:N \l_bp_mylist_clist }
 {
  \regex_match:neTF { [0-9]+ } { \clist_item:Nn \l_bp_mylist_clist { #1 } }
   { Item~#1~`\clist_item:Nn \l_bp_mylist_clist { #1 }'~is~a~number \par }
   { Item~#1~`\clist_item:Nn \l_bp_mylist_clist { #1 }'~is~not~a~number \par }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

[image]